# Import gns3 data structure from file to variable

Tags: perl

I have a data structure as shown below in a external text file. it's much bigger, but the format remains the same. How can i use this file to make a perl data structure i can work with. I'm thinking i can do a file copy and replace all : with =>. but what next to use this external code a variable.

as if the was

```
my $hashref = FILE;
```

Thanks in advance

The file's format

```
 {
    "auto_close" => "true",
    "topology" => {
        "drawings" => [],
        "links" => [
            {
                "link_id" => "2c1a64c9-a96e-4c94-ac3d-bbaeadde3773",
                "nodes" => [
                    {
                        "adapter_number" => 2,
                        "label" => {
                            "rotation" => 0,
                            "style" => "font-family =>",
                        },
                        "node_id" => "0807cfc6-ffc9-4762-ad11-d021e2e49b0e",
                    },
                    {
                        "adapter_number" => 0,
                        "label" => {
                            "rotation" => 0,
                            "style" => "fill-opacity => 1.0;",
                        },
                        "node_id" => "aeab6b0b-6fd3-43d8-a547-7cd2752dc800",
                        "port_number" => 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "nodes" => [
            {
                "compute_id" => "local",
                "label" => {
                    "rotation" => 0,
                    "style" => "font-family => TypeWriter;",
                    "text" => "East1",
                },
                "name" => "East1",
                "properties" => {
                    "auto_delete_disks" => "true",
                    "platform" => "c7200",
                    "power_supplies" => [
                        1,
                        1
                    ],
                    "sensors" => [
                        22
                    ],
                },
                "symbol" => " =>/symbols/router.svg",
                "z" => 1
            }, 
        ]
    },
    "type" => "topology",
    "version" => "2.0.3"
};
```

Comment: Would eval work for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Slurp;

my $text=read_file($ARGV[0]);
$text=~s/:/ =>/g;
$text=~s/true/"true"/g;
$text=~s/false/"false"/g;
$text=~s/null/"null"/g;

my $ref= eval $text;
```